# What does a simple IF always return true?

Tags: php

Why does the following code always return true?

```
<?php
$v = "dav6d";
if($v = "david") {
echo "smith";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're assigning $v in your if, not comparing values. It should be "==" or "===" instead of "=".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if($v = "david")` is assigning, not comparing

```
$v="david"; // This code assign "david" to $v
$v=="david"; // This code compares $v vs "david"
```

Answer (score 11):

This line:

```
if($v = "david") {
```

is using an assignment (i.e. a single `=` sign) which will return the result of $v, `"david"`, which is a truthy value. If you want to do a comparison use `==` or `===`

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yes - see [http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Aha! (not a php programmer, I though you might have mistaken his code for javascript, but instead I learned something :)

Comment: "[...] which will return a true value", well yes, to be a bit more precise, an assignment expression returns the assigned value, in this case `"david"` which is a truthy value.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're setting `$v` to `"david"` in the if statement. Use `==` instead:

```
<?php
$v = "dav6d";
if($v == "david") {
  echo "smith";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

for avoiding such type mistakes, use the variable in second position(right side of comparison operator(here '`==`')) just like below

```
if("david"==$v) {
echo "smith";
}
```

It helps by producing syntax error message in-case, when you mistakenly put '`=`' instead of '`==`'